# Office 365 management api doesn't return the actual TargetUserOrGroupType

Tags: office365api

I've shared a file in onedrive with a different user and used [Office 365 management api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/) to search for it.
I did find the event but I can see that `TargetUserOrGroupType` is always `SharePointGroup` (although I shared with multiple users) the `TargetUserOrGroupName` is `SharingLinks.<some id>.AnonymousEdit.<some id>` .

Why don't I see the name of the users I shared the file with?